# Part of Menu Item Hidden on Header Menu

Tags: theme-development, menus, sitemap

My business site is built on WordPress and I am using the "Shifters Lite" WP theme right now.

My issue is:

One of my primary menu item (designed as per my web-pages) is getting hidden on the Header part. The page in concern is - Sitemap.

For better understanding, you can view my site here: http://aadhyaexim.com/

As clearly visible, the last letter of the word "Sitemap" is getting hidden automatically.

I tried multiple CSS codes, but none of them worked in my favor. So, thought of asking the experts here.

Any help in this regards would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're skewing the parent container with CSS transforms.
You can see in this screen capture of developer tools that the parent cuts off the content on the second row.
[image: Skewed Parent]

Try this:

```
.menu-primary-menu-container{margin-right:10px;}
```

You'll see that fixes it, so you just play around with those settings and get it exactly how you want it.

Here's what happens when I add that rule in the developer tools:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this CSS code, @Tony. It worked perfect for me. Is there any way, wherein I can align all these menu items horizontally in a single line? 
Please let me know in case that can be done.

Comment: You can but it will always depend on the width of the screen.  The parent container is set to 75% so it’ll scale as screen width reduces.  To get the items in a single line try reducing the left and right padding on the <li> or the <a> tags a bit which will reduce the space between and then try to reduce the font size by 1 or 2 pixels.  If you do both of those you should get them on a single line and can remove the margin-right added in my answer above.

Comment: Thank you @Tony for explaining the process. Will give this a try tonight and update you.

Comment: Manu Mathur, any luck with your updates?